# Add frame and logo on all pages

Tags: graphics, page-numbering, bounding-box

I am not able to do both these commands at the same time. The both work separatly. I would also like to put page numbering at the bottom right of all pages. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}

%for black  frame on each page
% \usetikzlibrary{calc}
% \SetBgScale{1}
% \SetBgAngle{0}
% \SetBgColor{black}
% \SetBgOpacity{1}
% \SetBgContents{
% \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
% \draw [line width=1.5pt]
%     ($ (current page.north west) + (0.4in,-0.4in) $)
%     rectangle
%     ($ (current page.south east) + (-0.4in,0.4in) $);
% \end{tikzpicture}}

%for logo on each page
\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  color=black,
  opacity=1,
  angle=0,
  position=current page.south,
  vshift=1in,
  contents={%
  \small\sffamily
  \begin{minipage}{.18\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=25pt,keepaspectratio]{logo_cosinus.jpg} %logo goes here
  \end{minipage}%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion using `scrlayer-scrpage`. Then you can declare a new layer for the frame and another for the logo. This layers can be added to one pagestyle like `scrheadings`, `plain`, `empty` etc. or to all layer pagestyles `@everystyle@`.

I have used `\fbox` to insert the frame so there is no need to load `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}[2015/10/03]
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot{\pagemark}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  voffset=.4in+.75pt,
  hoffset=.4in-.75pt,
  addwidth=-.8in-1.5pt,
  addheight=-.8in-1.5pt,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\putLL{%
    \setlength\fboxrule{1.5pt}\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \fbox{\parbox[b][\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{\mbox{}}}%
    }}]{frame}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  bottommargin,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\put(\LenToUnit{.5\layerwidth},\LenToUnit{1in}){%
    \includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=25pt,keepaspectratio]{example-image.pdf}%
}}]{logo}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{frame,logo}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While `background` is a nice package for `underlay`, `fancyhdr` (for example) is nice to display the page number at definite positions.

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyfoot{} % Clear the footer
  \rfoot{\thepage} % set the page number at the right footer. 
}
```

In principle the image could be set with `\cfoot{\includegraphics...}` instead of using `background`.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}

%for black  frame on each page
% \usetikzlibrary{calc}
% \SetBgScale{1}
% \SetBgAngle{0}
% \SetBgColor{black}
% \SetBgOpacity{1}
% \SetBgContents{
% \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
% \draw [line width=1.5pt]
%     ($ (current page.north west) + (0.4in,-0.4in) $)
%     rectangle
%     ($ (current page.south east) + (-0.4in,0.4in) $);
% \end{tikzpicture}}

%for logo on each page
\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  color=black,
  opacity=1,
  angle=0,
  position=current page.south,
  vshift=1in,
  contents={%
  \small\sffamily
  \begin{minipage}{.18\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=25pt,keepaspectratio]{beeduck.jpg} %logo goes here
  \end{minipage}%
  }
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyfoot{}
  \rfoot{\thepage}
}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not put the two actions in a single block?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} %
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % remove footer rule
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

%% For black  frame on each page + Logo
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [line width=1.5pt]
($ (current page.north west) + (0.4in,-0.4in) $)
rectangle
($ (current page.south east) + (-0.4in,0.4in) $);
\node at ([yshift=1in]current page.south){\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=25pt,keepaspectratio]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**geometry** has the ability to display a frame to reveal the page layout for debugging purposes. As it is, this is of little use as the frame around the page allows no separation between frame and text and, besides, it also draws a bunch of other lines marking other aspects of the page layout.

However, I figured that it ought to be possible to concoct a parasitic package which would hook into **geometry**'s functionality and add a more flexibly-defined frame in the same way, or in addition to, the debugging markings available from the package itself.

This answer begins by explaining `geometry-frames.sty` with a straightforward example. It then illustrates how to combine this with the code from the question to satisfy the three desiderata (frame, logo and page number).

## `geometry-frames.sty`

This package is based on code directly modified from `geometry.sty` and uses that package's mechanism to add the frame to the page.

The user interface provides the following commands:

- `\GeometryFrame[<margin around text>][<thickness of frame rule>]` adds frames to pages according to the specified values or, if none are specified, the defaults. The default is for a `5pt` margin around the text and a `.4pt` rule for the frame.
- `\NoGeometryFrame` switches off the addition of frames.

Both commands affect the current page and all subsequent pages.

Here's a demonstration for a document with a double-sided layout on A4 paper with 3 settings:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
% \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% for showing debugging layout frames provided by geometry
\usepackage{geometry-frames}
\begin{document}
\GeometryFrame
first first first first As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
\newpage
\GeometryFrame[5pt][10pt]
first first first first As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
\newpage
\NoGeometryFrame
first first first first As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

If we add **geometry**'s debugging frame to display the layout, we can see what is happening in more detail:

[image: demo with layout marked up]

## Illustration

Turning to the code provided in the question, here's a first attempt to use the new commands to add a frame to the page with the desired characteristics.

We start by loading the package.

```
\usepackage{geometry-frames}
```

To avoid having the page number clash with the frame, we either need to reduce `footskip` (to put the number within the frame) or increase it (to put the number outside the frame). I assume first that the number should be inside and use **geometry**'s `\geometry` to increase the `footskip`. It is important that any changes to the layout be done with **geometry** or strange things will happen. (This is always true when using the package - not just with my additions.)

```
\geometry{footskip=.2in}
```

Now we set the frame with the desired values of a `.4in` margin around the text and `1.5pt` thick rules for the frame.

```
\GeometryFrame[.4in][1.5pt]
```

That's the frame done. Now for the page number. Since you are already using **fancyhdr**, this is straightforward.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf[rf]{\thepage}
```

We offset the footer within the frame by a value equal to `\footskip` to keep things more-or-less symmetrical.

```
\fancyheadoffset[rf]{.2in}
```

The result:

[image: demo with page number inside frame]

If you want the page number outside the frame, then use different values for `\footskip` and `\fancyheadoffset`. For example,

```
\geometry{footskip=1.4in}
```

and

```
\fancyheadoffset[rf]{.9in}
```

produce

[image: number outside frame]

## Complete code

The `filecontents` environment is just for convenience so that `geometry-frames.sty` will be written the first time the code is compiled. The package code can, of course, just be saved directly as `geometry-frames.sty` if you prefer.

```
\begin{filecontents}{geometry-frames.sty}% package code
\ProvidesPackage{geometry-frames}
\RequirePackage{geometry,etoolbox,xparse,calc}
\newif\ifgeometryframes@frame@page
\geometryframes@frame@pagetrue
\NewDocumentCommand\GeometryFrame { O {5pt} O {.4pt} }
{%
  \setlength\geometryframes@frame@page@margin{#1}%
  \setlength\geometryframes@frame@page@rule{#2}%
  \geometryframes@frame@pagetrue
}
\NewDocumentCommand\NoGeometryFrame {}
{%
  \geometryframes@frame@pagefalse
}
\newlength\geometryframes@frame@page@margin
\newlength\geometryframes@frame@page@rule
\newlength\geometryframes@width
\newlength\geometryframes@height
\newdimen\geometryframes@moveright
\AtBeginDocument{% modified from geometry.sty
  \if@tempswa\relax\else
  \RequirePackage{atbegshi}%
  \AtBeginShipout{\setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\vbox{%
      \baselineskip\z@skip\lineskip\z@skip\lineskiplimit\z@
      \Gm@pageframes\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}}%
  \fi
}
\apptocmd\Gm@pageframes{% modified from \Gm@pageframes
 \ifgeometryframes@frame@page
   \setlength\geometryframes@width{\textwidth+2\geometryframes@frame@page@margin}%
   \setlength\geometryframes@height{\textheight+2\geometryframes@frame@page@margin+2\geometryframes@frame@page@rule}%
   \if@twoside
     \ifodd\count\z@
       \let\@themargin\oddsidemargin
     \else
       \let\@themargin\evensidemargin
     \fi
    \fi
    \let\geometryframes@moveright\@themargin
    \advance\geometryframes@moveright by -\geometryframes@frame@page@margin
    \moveright\geometryframes@moveright%
    \vb@xt@\z@{%
     \vskip\topmargin
     \vskip\headheight
     \vskip -\geometryframes@frame@page@margin
     \vskip\headsep\vb@xt@\z@{\vss\geometryframes@hrule}%
     \vskip -\geometryframes@frame@page@rule
     \geometryframes@vrules
     \vb@xt@\z@{\vss\geometryframes@hrule}%
     \vss}%
    \fi%
  }{\typeout{patch applied!}}{\typeout{oh, no!}}%
\newcommand*{\geometryframes@vrules}{% modified from \Gm@vrules@mpi
  \hb@xt@\geometryframes@width{\llap{\geometryframes@vrule}\ignorespaces
  \hskip \geometryframes@width\geometryframes@vrule}}%
\def\geometryframes@vrule{\vrule width \geometryframes@frame@page@rule height\geometryframes@height depth\z@}% modified from \Gm@vrule
\def\geometryframes@hrule{\hrule height \geometryframes@frame@page@rule depth\z@ width\geometryframes@width}% ditto for \Gm@hrule
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry-frames}
\geometry{footskip=.2in}
% \geometry{footskip=1.4in}
\GeometryFrame[.4in][1.5pt]
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf[rf]{\thepage}
\fancyheadoffset[rf]{.2in}
% \fancyheadoffset[rf]{.9in}
\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=1,
  color=black,
  opacity=1,
  angle=0,
  position=current page.south,
  vshift=1in,
  contents={%
  \small\sffamily
  \begin{minipage}{.18\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=25pt,keepaspectratio]{cath}%
  \end{minipage}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```